# Stored procedure gives timeout error sometime

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure which sometime gives timeout error and another time it runs fine. I have ensured that on all tables from which I select have no locks. Any suggestions? What will be the issue?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Unfortunately your question doesn't provide enough details to determine the problem. Please review [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question with the additional details (example code would be good).

Comment: We need to know **what concrete database** you're using (SQL is just the query language - not a database product), and we should see the stored procedure code, to be able to diagnose anything.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help you:

[How to set timeout for a stored procedure in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005254/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server)

If not - then determine why the query runs for so long and try to optimize it.