# How to Control a Long-Running Query

Tags: c#, sql-server

We are currently managing a web application that runs stored procedures, one of which is triggered whenever a user searches for a particular item. Unfortunately we encountered a very serious issue one day for this SP as it went long-running, thus it caused the database to perform very poorly. This eventually caused a lot of problems for our applications. I found out that a long-running query was causing the problem by running this database script:

```
SELECT sqltext.TEXT,
req.session_id,
req.status,
req.command,
req.cpu_time,
req.total_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
where
    sqltext.[Text] NOT LIKE '--''check%'
ORDER BY req.cpu_time DESC
```

So what we did to fix this was to execute KILL [SESSION_ID] and after a few seconds our application was back to normal. Now, we would like to handle this type of problem proactively so when I say control, I would like to know if it is possible for the web application to terminate this session gracefully (not causing subsequent problems) after a certain period or time or should it be handled within SQL Server itself?

If anyone still needs further clarification, please feel free to comment.

Comment: you will need to fine tune those queries which are performing poorly,thats the only option

Comment: Are you using connection timeout in your application?

Comment: Maybe try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4005428/5358389

Comment: Real way to go is of course fix your queries. If that cannot be done, there is such thing as Resource Governor is sql server: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933866.aspx. It should do what you want, but I must admit I have never used it myself.

Comment: The stored procedure uses a lot of parameter values since it is being used to search items based on a specific filter. The painpoint of this issue is that there is no way to know what filters were selected that have caused the query to run for a very long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really need where
    sqltext.[Text] NOT LIKE '--''check%'
1.sys.dm_exec_requests also has a start time column, which you currently are not using the where clause. Pass in a start time, so its not going to the beginning of all the data
2. look at the data and try to modify the where clause accordingly. 
3. Pull the execution plan for the proc pretty sure it will to do a table scan which is not good.

Here are the steps to get the execution plan
Step 1 
Please modify dates, proc db name

```
select distinct top 1000 qs.plan_handle,o.name,d.name--,--ps.database_id
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats  qs
    ,sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats    ps
    ,sys.objects o
    ,sys.databases d
where qs.last_execution_time > '2017-03-29 17:06:42.340' 
and qs.last_execution_time < '2017-03-30 18:19:45.653'
and ps.sql_handle = qs.sql_handle
and o.object_id = ps.object_id
AND o.name = 'Your proc name here'
AND d.database_id = ps.database_id
AND d.name = 'database name '
```

Step 2
Set output to grid and save as .sqlplan
You get a link, if you have enough permissions you can click on it and it will open. Make sure the have query output options set so there is enough space given
for xml output.

```
select query_plan
from sys.dm_exec_query_plan (copy your handle here from step 1, do no use quotes)
```

Comment: How will I pull this execution plan?

Comment: Updated the Answer with details on how to get the execution plan